# In the two URI design patterns below, which is more RESTful?

Tags: rest, restful-url

In the two URI design patterns below, which is more RESTful?
1) project/123/engineer/somebody/abilities
2) abilities?engineer=somebody&project=123

Comment: REST is about much more than just URLs so you might want to rephrase the question a bit.  But if you are looking for opinions on which is better, I would say the second for sure.  The resource is the set of abilities, which you filter with query parameters.  The top one _could_ be considered RESTful in that each partial path names a resource, but you should make project and engineer plural IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difference between these two is that #1 is a resource identifier and #2 is a query

Both are RESTful, though choice depends on purpose.